# Are there any tools to integrate MS SQL Server Reporting with Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, ssrs-2008

I need to pull some reports that live in a SQL Server Reporting Server from a Ruby web application.

How can this be done?

Comment: I am not particularly familiar with Ruby but I know RS exposes some web services that can be used to execute a report and return the result in a given format, such as PDF.  Might be one direction to explore.

Comment: @Rozwel Thanks! I think I might have to go that route, but I just wanted to ask the community if there are any tools similar to the .Net ReportViewer class. Where the end user can navigate, print, or export the report without having to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing out there pre-built that I'm aware of, but you have some options for integration.

The simplest, if users have direct access to the RS server, is to just redirect or link them to the report using their URL-based strategy, possibly opening a new window.  If users do not have direct access, you can still use the URL-based strategy, but perform a request on the back end from your Rails app to the MS Reporting Services server, and stream all the report bytes through to the browser:

```
open("http://ReportServer/reports?querystringxxxx") { |f|
    @response = f.read
}
```

This is drastically simplified, of course.  You'll need to pay particular attention to your content types to ensure things get interpreted correctly by the browser.

The next option is to use their web services API, but unless you need particularly advanced functionality, I'd say the URL/REST based approach is far, far simpler.

If you get it working, take the opportunity to try creating your first gem, put it up on github, and then maybe somebody else will use it one day... :)

Answer (score 1):

The rest-based approach would only work for a report with no parameters.

If the report has parameters, you will need to use the Web Services API, a SOAP-based interface that requires you to parse the request (with the parameters) into XML and send that with the request to MSSRS.

According to my co-worker, who has done it, it's pretty cumbersome for what you actually get.